# jquery are all images hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden

I have a div and inside that div are a lot of images. Some are hidden and some are not. Is there a simple way to find out if all images are hidden? The code below will fire if some of the images are hidden. I want it to fire only if all images are hidden.
Thanks.

```
if ($('#images' img").is(":hidden"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it this way:

```
var images = $('#images img');
if(images.filter(':hidden').length == images.length)
{
   //all are hidden
}
```

By the way there is a syntax error in `$('#images' img")` due to unmatched quotes.

Also checking `$('#images img').is(":hidden")` will provide you the status of true if atleast one of the images is hidden.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNEuF/)

See [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

*Do remember that this won't work with `visibility:hidden`*

Comment: Thats cool, just what I wanted. Thanks. Also thanks for explaining why!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was pretty close, but you need to think about it just the opposite.  Consider checking to see if any images *are* visible -- if so, then all images can't be hidden.

This should work well:

```
    if (!$('#images img').is(":visible")) {
        alert("Do Something");
    }
```

- [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Us854/)